# Is it better to use TFloatPoint or TFixedPoint in GR32?

Tags: delphi, graphics, vector-graphics

For building a scene graph a decision needs to be made between using TFixedPoint and TFloatPoint for all geometries and math. GR32 uses both Fixed and Float.

1. Why are there two point types in GR32?
2. Which is faster / more efficient?
3. Which is safer?
4. Any other suggestions re this issue?

Operational boundaries for the graph:

1. max 500 primitives/elements per node, avg is 20
2. max 2000 nodes per scene, avg is 250

Features for the graph:

1. Graphics are 2d
2. Graphics must be of a high visual quality
3. Animation is required
4. Isometric projections is required

The intended use for the graph:

1. Business graphics (charts, grids etc)
2. Modeling tool
3. Textual presentation
4. Process simulations

Comment: Well, it depends. How about some more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed Point math is generally faster, so TFixedPoint will perform faster mathematically.

Floating Point can (depending on the degree of precision employed on Fixed Point values) provide greater precision than Fixed Point, but will not perform as quickly in terms of mathematical routines.

"Safety" is too subjective to answer... safer how?

As per your final part-question, it depends what you value more: precision or performance.

If precision is your primary objective, go with TFloatPoint. If performance is your primary objective, go with TFixedPoint.